# Igualar variável javascript a uma variavel em php

Tags: javascript, php, webforms

Tenho um formulário, e antes do formulário ser submetido quero validar se o campo `nome_carro` existe igual na base de dados. Para fazer esta validação estou a usar javascript.

No formulário tenho o seguinte:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="add_form"  onsubmit="return validateForm()"> 
     <input type="text" name="nome_carro" required="">
     .
     .
     .
</form>
```

E no javascript o seguinte:

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["add_form"]["nome_carro"].value;
    <?php
        $nome_carro = "VARIAVEL X, NO JAVASCRITP";
        //fazer query, mas para isso preciso da variavel $nome_carro preenchida
    ?>
    var nome_carro_bd = <?php $valor_retornado_da_consulta?>;
    if(x == nome_carro_bd)
    {
        alert("Por favor, insira outro nome na viatura. O nome que colocou já existe.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Para fazer a validação no javascript, tenho que fazer uma consulta à BD(usando php) para verificar se o nome já existe. Para tal preciso de igualar a variável `x` a uma variavel php para poder fazer a query. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não dá para fazer assim inline, você precisa de uma requisição ajax ao servidor.

Comment: e sem ser por ajax, existe outra alternativa?

Comment: Nâo. O PHP executa ANTES do Javscript.

Comment: Acredito que o jeito mais prático para realizar este procedimento seria usar um ajax, caso não tenha problema posso ajudar com o script.

Comment: Só se você guardar todos os valores do banco em uma array js antes de gerar a página, e depois ver se o valor do campo está na array. Se forem muitos, não é recomendado.

Comment: E não é possível ir buscar o nome do campo por php antes do formulário ser submetido?

Comment: Só por ajax. Quando o browser carrega a página, o PHP já terminou de executar.

Comment: @bfavaretto se carregar para um array, depois como posso fazer a comparação? Estou a pensar ir por esta solução

Comment: Se `nomeDoArray.indexOf('valor') > -1` quer dizer que achou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você vai precisar usar `Ajax` para realizar uma consulta e retornar se existe ou não este carro no banco de dados. Não é possível fazer da maneira que você quer porque a página já foi carregada.

Dê uma olhada neste link https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/